# How to get Form Data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a form in my angular 2 Project.

I know how to Retrieve data from the API. But don't know how to Perform a CRUD operation in there.

Can anybody help me with the simple codes on How to Send form data in JSON format to a Web Service in PHP/Any other Language...

Comment: check this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154319/how-to-post-json-object-with-http-post-angular-2-php-server-side

Comment: @AmitSuhag, i want to know how to bind the form data by both click event and onSubmit method. And then how to stringify it. Can you help me with a whole package solution... It will be very helpful for me...

Answer (score 45):

In Angular 2+ we handle forms two ways:

- Template-driven
- Reactive

Here I am sharing code for simple template-driven forms. If you want to do it using reactive forms then check this link: [Angular2 reactive form confirm equality of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138925/angular2-reactive-form-confirm-equality-of-values/41139110#41139110)

Your module file should have these:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyApp } from './components'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [MyApp],
  bootstrap: [MyApp]
})
export class MyAppModule {

}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule)
```

Simple registration html file:

```
<form #signupForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(signupForm)">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ngModel>

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ngModel>

  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Now your registration.ts file should be like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'register-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/register-form.component.html',
})
export class RegisterForm {
  registerUser(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    // {email: '...', password: '...'}
    // ... <-- now use JSON.stringify() to convert form values to json.
  }
}
```

To handle this data on server side use this link: [How to post json object with Http.post (Angular 2) (php server side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154319/how-to-post-json-object-with-http-post-angular-2-php-server-side). I think this is more than sufficient.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for the help on this

Comment: can anyone help  me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319200/fetch-all-values-in-form-using-ngmodel-directive-in-angular

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by passing `user.value` to submit method, please see the following example:

**app.component.html**

```
<form #user="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user.value)">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" ngModel required>
  <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" ngModel required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor() { }
   onSubmit(data) {
      console.log("Email: " + data.email
                 +"Password: " + data.passwd);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
Name<input type="text" formControlName="name"><br><br>
City<select formControlName="city">
    <option value="kkp">KKP</option>
    <option value="MKT">MKT</option>
</select><br><br>
```

-->

formData:FormGroup;

```
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.formData = new FormGroup({
        name    : new FormControl(),
        city    : new FormControl()
    });
}
onSubmit(){ 

    console.log(this.formData.value);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Ways to get form value in Angular application**

1. Using formControlName (Reactive Form)
2. Using document object
3. Using local reference object
4. Using ngModel (Template-driven Form)
5. Using ViewChild
6. Using Input native events

[Click here](https://jsonworld.com/blog/different-ways-to-get-form-data-in-angular-component) to read in detail.