# Angular Form validation values asssign to interface

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Here I'm having simple form as

```
<form [formGroup]="loginform">
<input type="text" formControlName="EmailId"/>
<input type="text" formControlName="password"/>
<button [disabled]="!loginform.valid" (click)="ValidateUser()"></button>
<form>
```

My Ts code as
loginform!:FormGroup;
Here im mentioned my validation as

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginform=this.fb.group({
      EmailId:['',[Validators.required]],
      password:['',[Validators.required]
    })
  }
```

Geing values as

```
 get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.loginform.controls;
  }
```

Here is my Interface

```
export interface logindetails{
    EmailId:string;
    password:string;
}
```

on my submission

```
ValidateUser(objuser:logindetails){
}
```

from my HTML to here how can I bind values to my interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add these on your `.ts` file:

```
onEmailIdChanged(event:any){
    this.EmailId = event.target.value;

  }
  onPasswordChanged(event:any){
    this.password = event.target.value;
  }
```

and on your `.HTML` do this:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="EmailId" (change)="onEmailIdChanged($event)/>
<input type="text" formControlName="password" (change)="onPasswordChanged($event)/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you want strongly typed reactive form

Declaring the interfaces

```
interface ILoginForm {
   EmailId: string;
   password: string;
}

// Interface IUserFormGroup extends FormGroup {
   loginForm: ILoginForm;

   // We need to add these manually again, same fields as ILoginForm
   controls: {
      EmailId: AbstractControl;
      password: AbstractControl;
   };
}
```

Initializing the formbuilder group

```
form: ILoginForm;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
  // initialize the form
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    EmailId:['',[Validators.required]],
    password:['',[Validators.required]
  }) as ILoginForm; // make sure to double-check this list with the interface
}

const loginData: ILoginForm = this.form.value; // this is now valid typescript

ValidateUser(){
  const loginData: ILoginForm = this.form.value; // this is now valid typescript
  console.log(`Login data ${loginData.EmailId}`);
}
```

More advanced and generic solution [Angular strongly typed reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053466/angular-strongly-typed-reactive-forms/56476352#56476352)