# Angular 14 strictly typed reactive forms using Generics

Tags: angular, forms, generics, reactive

```
export type ModelFormGroup\<T\> = FormGroup\<{
\[K in keyof T\]: FormControl\<T\[K\]\>;
}\>;
```

I need generic interface for formcontrol and formArray.

I am able to create form control. but I dont know how to use for formarray.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below generic type that works for both FormControl and FormArray, and allows defining form types using deeply nested interfaces.

```
export type TypedFormControls<T extends Record<any, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Array<infer R>
    ? FormArray<R extends Record<any, any> ? FormGroup<TypedFormControls<R>> : FormControl<R>>
    : T[K] extends Record<any, any>
    ? FormGroup<TypedFormControls<T[K]>>
    : FormControl<T[K]>;
};
```

See example below demonstrating how to declare your form type and construct the form. Note: You will need to use FormBuilder's `fb.control(...)` and `fb.array(...)` methods.

```
interface Baz {
  bazA: number;
}

interface Bar {
  barA: string;
  barB: number;
  barC: string[];
}

interface Foo {
  fooA: string[];
  fooB: Bar;
  fooC: Baz[];
}

type FooTypedForm = TypedFormControls<Foo>;

class TypedFormExample {
  form = this.fb.group<FooTypedForm>({
    fooA: this.fb.array<string>([]),
    fooB: this.fb.group<TypedFormControls<Bar>>({
      barA: this.fb.control(''),
      barB: this.fb.control(0),
      barC: this.fb.array<string>([]),
    }),
    fooC: this.fb.array<FormGroup<TypedFormControls<Baz>>>([
      this.fb.group<TypedFormControls<Baz>>({
        bazA: this.fb.control(1),
      }),
    ]),
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you could try something like:

```
export class GenericFormArray<T extends AbstractControl> extends FormArray {
  constructor(controls: T[]) {
    super(controls);
  }
}

const fb = new FormBuilder();
const formArray = new GenericFormArray([
   fb.array([{age: 25, name: "fu"}, {age: 12, name: "bar"}]),
]);
```

Have you looked at: [Angular strongly typed reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55053466/16915945)?